# Azure worker role deployment issue while publishing from Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-worker-roles

I have a Cloud Project for Worker Role in Visual Studio 2015, where i'm trying to deploy the same project using my azure credentials.

Getting the following exception, i tried to figure it out by googling, but no luck.

Any help/suggestion would be helpful.

> Applying Diagnostics extension.

***Description:***

> Could not find key for storage account ordastorage in the known
>   subscriptions. Provide a key manually or make sure Visual Studio is
>   connected to the subscription containing the storage account.

What would be the issue or possible cause?

Comment: When we publish the code on Azure, first it uploads the package to the Azure storage account. Looking at the error, it seems that either your Azure subscription do not have the storage account name "ordastorage "

Answer (score 1):

> Could not find key for storage account ordastorage in the known subscriptions. Provide a key manually or make sure Visual Studio is connected to the subscription containing the storage account.

According to the exception, it indicates that you try to use the storage that is not under your subscription. To publish a cloud service project, you could set up the following services as described in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-cloud-service-publish-set-up-required-services-in-visual-studio):

> - A cloud service to run your roles in the Azure environment, and
> - A storage account that provides access to the Blob, Queue, and Table services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually solved the problem by changing the option `Service Configuration` to `Local` in the window *Publish Azure Application*. Earlier it was `Cloud`. Not sure what was the exact reason behind this.

Comment: Take a look at this screen shot [Azure Settings Image](https://i.imgur.com/q7dLUGL.png)